# Can I copy innerHTML for a div without ignoring white spaces?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I`m trying to copy a div html content to another element as a text , but when I try that it ignores the white spaces, any idea how that can be done?

here is my code:

***HTML***

```
<div id="parent">
     <!-- Component: -->
  <div id="component" class="">
    <p class="px-8 text-center py-2  bg-green-500 text-white 
              dark:bg-green-50 dark:text-green-900
              font-medium text-lg rounded-md 
              hover:scale-105 hover:bg-green-100
              ">
      Start Now
    </p>
  </div>

<!-- Code: -->

  <div class="px-8 my-8">
      <h1 class="text-white ">Code:</h1>
      <p class="text-white" id="code"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

***JS***

```
const component = document.getElementById("component")
const code = document.querySelector("#code")

code.innerText=component.innerHTML
```

*What I get:*
[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dV0QA.png)

*What I want:*
[what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nJg8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that the whitespace is being ignored, but rather how the browser displays particular elements. HTML elements each have their own predefined styles & characteristics, typically defined via user agent stylesheets.

Given that you want to honor the whitespace, you can either use css attribute [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#pre) or change `#code` to a `<pre>` tag instead of a `<p>` (downside is you will still need to override default browser styles).

```js
const comp = document.getElementById('component');
const original = document.getElementById('codeoriginal');
const code = document.getElementById('code');
const code2 = document.getElementById('code2');

original.innerText = comp.innerHTML;
code.innerText = comp.innerHTML;
code2.innerText = comp.innerHTML;
```

```css
#code {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
     <!-- Component: -->
  <div id="component" class="">
    <p class="px-8 text-center py-2  bg-green-500 text-white 
              dark:bg-green-50 dark:text-green-900
              font-medium text-lg rounded-md 
              hover:scale-105 hover:bg-green-100
              ">
      Start Now
    </p>
  </div>

<!-- Code: -->

  <div class="px-8 my-8">
      <h1 class="text-white ">Code: (Original)</h1>
      <p class="text-white" id="codeoriginal"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="px-8 my-8">
      <h1 class="text-white ">Code: (CSS change)</h1>
      <p class="text-white" id="code"></p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="px-8 my-8">
      <h1 class="text-white ">Code: (Using pre)</h1>
      <pre class="text-white" id="code2"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, sir that was simple and solved my problem!

Comment: @Dhaifallah Glad I could help! Happy coding!